# Showing.a contextual menu on hold on mobile

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have several thumbnails with a contextual menu tied to each one. On hold of a thumbnail on mobile, I want to show the respective contextual menu. Does anyone know how to trigger this "hold" effect on mobile? Is it using the click javascript event listener?